# plot 1d curves in 3d space with nice looking intersections

Tags: diagrams, 3d

I am trying to draw multiple colored one-dimensional parametric 
               curves in three dimensional euclidean space.  The curves 
               themselves do not intersect in 3d, but sometimes their 
               projections intersect when projected into 2d for visualization. 
               In these cases, I would like the color at the intersection to 
               be the color of the curve 'in front.'

The problem is that the curves are not strictly ordered (they 
               could be knot-like) so I have some variant of the painter's 
               problem, except a bit simpler because all my objects are 
               one-dimensional and they do not intersect in 3d.

Is there a nice LaTeX or related thing that could help me with 
               this?  I've looked at examples for asymptote and some other ps 
               and tikz packages but I can't find a nice example where this is 
               done automatically.

Currently my work-around is to break all of the curves into 
               tiny segments and then depth sort.  This works as long as the 
               segments are small relative to the minimum distance between 
               curves in 3d, I think.  But it is a hack and is ugly.

Comment: Try to visit [PSTricks 3D Examples](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/3D/examples) and [PSTricks 3D Gallery](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery3D/Gallery3D).

Comment: I believe even all the PSTricks examples showing this, doesn't sort, or sorts manually.

Comment: PSTricks can draw lines with hidden elements.

Comment: @Herbert; But does it do correct Z-buffering? The 3D-wave example shows exactly the problem addressed in the question.

Comment: @Mikael: How should we then draw 3d elements with hidden lines and surfaces? http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pst-solides3d/doc/doc-exemples-solides3d/?page=4

Comment: @Herbert: I'm just saying this is the exact problem texnub asked: http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/3D/examples and in your example, no single face or line is both in front and behind something, which gives a trivial z-order

Comment: @Mikael: All examples on that page are of parallel projection _without_ any hidden lines and surfaces! I am talking about the package `pst-solides3d` and not `pst-3dplot`.

Comment: @Herbert: As far as i can see, for every **parameterized curve**, the ordering is done manually. Drawing lines with `\pstThreeDLine` the appear in order, regardless of actual depth. Fusing solids as done in pst-solides3d seems irrelevant to this question, as does `hiddenLine`.

Comment: For breaking the curves, it should suffice to break them at all the local extrema of the x-coordinate of the 2d projection. (Or the y-coordinate, or any fixed linear combination of the x and y-coordinates.) This is because the path cannot self-intersect without "going backwards" relative to any given direction.

Answer (score 1):

Doing these computations in tex is usually not a pretty sight, so Z-ordering is mostly absent in these plotting tools. I believe you need to look into an external tool, like [sketch](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/3d-cone/) which can generate the tikz code for you.